# OCaml rev_int function

Tags: ocaml

With my original code I kept getting `Error: Parse error: [expr level ;] expected after "in" (in [expr])` on the line `let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in`

Original:

> ```
> let rec rev_int num =
>   if num / 10 == 0 then
>      num
>   else
>     let temp = num mod 10 in
>
>     let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in
>
>     if num < 0 then
>       let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
>     else
>       let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in
>
>     let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
>     temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
> ```

With variations of:

> ```
> if num < 0 then
>    let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in;
> else
>    let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in;
> ```

---

> ```
> if num < 0 then
>    let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
> else begin
>    let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in end
> ```

I revised the code and now it works, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with nested if and less redundancy.

Revised:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    if num < 0 then
      let numDigits = numDigits - 1 in
      let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
      temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
    else
      let numDigits = numDigits + 0 in
      let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
      temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that in both branches you're doing the same calculation, so might want to begin by pushing the conditional in, obtaining:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    let numDigits = numDigits - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

Just an initial thought to get you started on improving the code.

Answer (score 3):

Nested ifs are just a minor problem with this function.  A much bigger problem is that the algorithm is poor.

It appears that you want to reverse the digits of an integer.  To do that, you are doing all kinds of costly conversions, like `string_of_int`, `float_of_int`, and `int_of_float`.  In particular, converting an `int` to a string actually involves many operations behind the scenes — just so that you can figure out how many places to left-shift your number!

What you want is a recursive algorithm that only manipulates the least-significant digits of numbers.

```
let rev_int num =
  let rec rev_int' n m = match n with
    | 0 -> m
    | n -> rev_int' (n / 10) (10 * m + (n mod 10))
  in rev_int' num 0
```

Answer (score 1):

From the revised version:

Factor the common code from both branches:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    let numDigits = numDigits - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    let num = (num - temp) / 10 in
    temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

`(num - temp) / 10 = num / 10` when `temp = num mod 10`:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let temp = num mod 10 in

    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 in

    let numDigits = numDigits - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    let num = num / 10 in
    temp * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) + rev_int num
```

Inline `temp` definition, as it is a terrible name anyway, and avoid rebinding the same name multiple times:

```
let rec rev_int num =
  if num / 10 == 0 then
    num
  else
    let numDigits = String.length(string_of_int num) - 1 
                    - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    num mod 10 * int_of_float(10.0 ** float_of_int numDigits) 
    + rev_int (num / 10)
```

Maybe more idiomatic ocaml: use snake_case and pattern matching (with is also more efficient: you don't recalculate `n / 10` twice) :

```
let rec rev_int num = 
  match num / 10 with
  | 0 -> num
  | q ->
    let num_digits = String.length (string_of_int num) - 1 
                     - (if num < 0 then 1 else 0) in
    num mod 10 * int_of_float (10.0 ** float_of_int num_digits) 
    + rev_int q
```